# Is it possible to format a chart axis label with leading 'figure spaces'?

Tags: .net, charts, string-formatting

I am looking to set up a chart axis with labels of a fixed length. In many typefaces, digits are the same length as 'figure spaces'. I understand using String.Format has some additional flexibilities that the Format string does not have.

Is there a string format the equivalent of "000.00" that would replacing the leading zeroes with leading 'figure' spaces?

Further, there exists a 'figure dash' that would be a monospace negation symbol, however I have not found the equivalent positive symbol of the correct standard length. Does one exist?

***See examples below***

: 012345678 Consecutive digits

: 0 2 4 6 8 'Figure spaces'

: 0 2 4 6 8 Regular spaces

: +239.33 Positive float

:   +4.34 Positive float with leading 'figure spaces'

:  239.33 Nominally positive floats with leading 'figure space'

:  ‒39.33 Negative float with leasing 'figure space' and 'figure dash'

:  -39.33 Negative float with leading 'figure space' and regular dash